# updating results

Tags: mysql

**TABLE1**

CREATE TABLE master (id INT Primarykey, start_point INT, data    BLOB ) the 'changes' table:

**Sample data**

1, 0, data1

2, 1, data2

3, 2, data3

4, 4, data4

5, 6, data5

6, 8, data6

**TABLE2**

CREATE TABLE changes (id INT, start_point INT,   user VARCHAR(10),  data      BLOB ) the user table:

**Sample data**

5, 6, user1, data5(with changed data)

3, 2, user2, data3( With changes)

4, 6, user2, data4(with changes)

5, 8, user2, data5 (with changes)

**TABLE3**
CREATE TABLE users (id INT, user VARCHAR(10) )

**Sample data**

1, user1

2, user1

3, user1

4, user1

5, user1

1, user2

2, user2

3, user2

4, user2

5, user2

final result for user1 should be (information of what id's for user1 will be provided by table3)

0, data1----from master

1, data2----from master

2, data3----from master

4, data4-----from master

6, data5...this is from changes

final result for user2 should be

0, data1

1, data2

2, data3

6, data4

8, data5

so this what i am trying to get.....my problem here i am getting the changed record from both changed and master table. i don't want the master record for the changed ones....can anyone help me?

Comment: I mean, you said please a bunch, but do you have any code or have you tried to even code a little of this? I dont want to do ALL of the homework for you...

Comment: Consider proving at the very least your table definitions, then some attempts to do it.

Comment: i have tried different option i couldn't update my post....but i have added my responce to the latest answer

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple application, try implementing it every way that you can think of.  It is unlikely that it would take more than an hour each, so in a day's time you are certain to hit upon the most effective implementation.

You will also discover that some schemes are so complicated or grungy that you won't be inspired to complete them.  That's all part of the engineering process.

In short, relax.  Just try a few ideas, perhaps initially writing the rough schema and the query to retrieve the data.  Also consider how hard it would be to write queries to populate the data, including referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very vague. I'm going to write what I think you mean, with a little SQL definition

the 'master' table:

```
CREATE TABLE master (
    id      INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT INDEX,
    data    BLOB
)
```

the 'changes' table:

```
CREATE TABLE changes (
    id        INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    master_id INT INDEX,
    data      BLOB
)
```

the user table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id   INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40)
)
```

Obviously these tables are not sufficient for what you want, but they will help to explain how you might join them together to do what I think you want.

Say you have the user ID and it is 4, and you want to acquire the data the user would want from the master table, and the changes that user has made to it. You might do something like so:

```
SELECT m.id master_id, m.data master_data, c.data change_data
    FROM master m
    JOIN changes c ON c.master_id = m.id
    WHERE m.user_id = 4;
```

This will get the master data that the user owns, and the changes to the data.

Comment: Thanks you both for the reply

Comment: @acpaps: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5628807/edit), not other people's answers.